# skrollr add/remove class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

i got a problem with prinzhorn/skrollr plugin for removeClass/addClass on scroll function.
I already tried to look up and got this method, but no luck for me.

```
<li class="tab col s3"><a data-800="@class: active" data-1000="@class: active" href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
<li class="tab col s3"><a data-1100="@class: active" data-1300="@class: active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
```

Please kindly check on my section code without the add class data-attribute.

```
<div id="about"
    data-0="display: none;"
    data-500="display: block; top: 100%;"
    data-800="top: 0%;"
    data-3000="top: 0%;"
    data-3100="top: -100%;"
>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="row" id="tab-nav">
            <div class="col s12">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or you check the fiddle in here > http://jsfiddle.net/8L6urrt5/

Any help would be great! Thanks before!

Comment: jsfiddle / example link?

Comment: @RooWM i already add the fiddle on my question. please kindly check it.

Comment: Where did you find the @class method? It seems this is not actually a feature, just something talked about here: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/99. This comment in that thread however, has a great / easy solution: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/99#issuecomment-68102729

Comment: @RooWM whoa, i probably missed this one. gotta try this, thank you! i'll let you know if it's working or not.

Comment: Of course, another great way is to incorporate the waypoints plugin in combo with this guy (also mentioned in a comment before)

Comment: Yup, waypoint is my only way out if i can't work it out with data-attribute. Anyway thanks for your info :)

Answer (score 5):

Using @class in a data-attribute is not actually a feature of scrollr, just something talked about as a requested feature here: github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/99.

You can use the data-attributes to add CSS in a similar fashion by doing the following:

```
<div class="blah" data-100="@myAttr: 0;" data-200="@myAttr: 1;" data-300="@myAttr: 1;" data-400="@myAttr: 0;" ></div>

.blah[myAttr="1"]{
    /* your style */
}
```

This solution provided by a comment in that same github thread: [github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/99#issuecomment-68102729](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/99#issuecomment-68102729)